# JUnit test AroundInvoke Interceptor

Tags: java, junit, cdi, weld, needle4j

```
class AbstractXYZClass{
 ...
 @AroundInvoke
 public Object intercept(InvocationContext ctx) ... {
   log("do intercepting");
   ctx.proceed();
 }
 ...
}

@Stateless
class XYZClass extends AbstractXYZClass{
 ...
 public void iWantToTestThisMethod() {...}
 ...
}
```

(running this on Server the interception for `iWantToTestThisMethod()` works fine)

In my unit tests (using Needle ...`@ObjectUnderTest(implementation=XYZClass.class)`...) `@AroundInvoke` doesn't get invoked

How can I JUnit-test  `XYZClass::iWantToTestThisMethod` with `intercept()` intercepting?

Answer (score 0):

Needle4j is a dependency injection "simulator", it does not support advanced lifecyles and scopes. So you will have to come up with a different testing strategy. 
I would stick to needle4j when it comes to injection and verification of correct method interactions but switch to something like [CDI-Unit](http://jglue.org/cdi-unit/) or Arquillian for the actual framework-behavior tests.